# Palindrome method logic error

Tags: java

I am writing a method that, when passed a string, returns 'true' if it is a palindrome and 'false' if it not a palindrome. The method ignores any punctuation marks and spaces in returning the palindrome. When I try to pass the string "Hannah", it returns false.

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String p){
  String backwardsOriginal = "";
  String blank = "";
  for(int i =0; i< p.length();i++){
     String lookAt = p.substring(i,i+1).toLowerCase();
     if ((!lookAt.equals(" ")) || (!lookAt.equals(",")) || (!lookAt.equals(".")) || (!lookAt.equals("!")) ||(!lookAt.equals("?"))) {
        blank+=lookAt.toLowerCase();
     }

  }
     for(int j=blank.length();j>=0;j--){
        if(j==0)
           backwardsOriginal +=blank.substring(0,j+1).toLowerCase();
        else
           backwardsOriginal += blank.substring(j-1,j).toLowerCase();
     }
        boolean k = true;
        int first = 0;
        int last = blank.length()-1;
        int ct = 0;
        while(k && (ct != blank.length())){
           if (last == 0) {
              if (blank.substring(blank.length()-1) != backwardsOriginal.substring(0,blank.length())) {
                 k=false;
              }
           } else if (last > 0) {
              if(blank.substring(first, first+1).equals(backwardsOriginal.substring(last-1,last))) {
                 k=true;
                 first++;
                 last--;
              } else {
                 k=false;
              }
           }
        }
        return k;  
     }
```

Comment: A suggestion, use `replaceAll` to replace all `,`|`.`|`?` with empty string, then iterate on the letters, it will make the program more easier.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am not allowed to use arrays, replace, replaceAll, or replaceFirst.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with a regular expression to convert everything not a word character (which is a special class regex `\W`, with words being `\w` - and in Java, we have to escape the `\` for the pattern). Then, I would lower case and convert the result to a `char[]`. Then, you only have to iterate half of the length of the array - if any characters aren't in the proper place `return false` - if you get to the end it is a palindrome. Like,

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String p) {
    char[] arr = p.replaceAll("\\W", "").toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    int len = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != arr[len - i - 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Which I tested with

```
System.out.println(isPalindrome("A Man, a Plan, a Canal Panama!"));
```

(it's `true`). And, based on your updated restrictions in the comments, you could implement the same algorithm with a `StringBuilder` (but you need two loops, one to build the "correct" `String` - the other to test if it is a palindrome). Like,

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String p) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length(); i++) {
        char ch = Character.toLowerCase(p.charAt(i));
        if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
            sb.append(ch);
        }
    }
    int len = sb.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
        if (sb.charAt(i) != sb.charAt(len - i - 1)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```